# Xcode Compiler Error when updating from Xcode 10 to Xcode 11.3.1

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, simulator

I'm trying to update my project from Xcode 10 to Xcode 11.3.1.
The project compiles in Xcode 10. When I go to compile the project in Xcode 11.3.1, I get an error that looks to indicate something might be wrong with the **Photos.framework**.
Here's a quick log image:

[This is the image showing the compilation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKcYY.png)

I'm using Swift 4.2.1  toolchain with Xcode 11.3.1. I don't want to update to Swift 5 until a later time since it'll be a lot of changes.

I've tried updating C++ Langauge Dialect to GNU++11 [-std=gnu++11], but the project still doesn't compile.

The question is if there is a workaround or some Xcode settings that I need to get the project to compile in Xcode 11.3.1.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Considering updating `Photos` framework so that it works with Swift 5. I believe you're getting those errors because your framework is outdated.

Comment: How do I update Photos framework?. It is a system library. I also tried creating a separate single view project with the specified environment. (Xcode 11.3.1, ToolChain: Swift 4.2.1): In the viewController, I import Photos and the same errors occurred. When I switch the toolchain to Xcode 11.3.1, it seems to compile again. But I would like to run it via Swift 4.2.1 Toolchain.